# Heroku scheduler execute a PHP file

Tags: php, file, heroku, scheduler

i'm trying to run a php script using the heroku scheduler. What command should i put in after the $ in heroku. I keep getting file not found. I have transferred the file i want to run to heroku but not luck with running it with the scheduler.

Comment: Hi papritiger, thanks for answering, i have tried that and still get file not found :/   What i'm not sure about is which directory heroku is set on. I'm assuming the directory of my application.

Comment: Yes, i got " /app " any ideas please?

Comment: You should be able to poke around with [__ls__ and __cd__](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Commands/File_System_Utilities). I only have a free heroku account so i can´t test it but this should be the root of your repository. If your file still is´nt showing up you may have neglected to commit or push the file up to heroku.

Comment: Hi again,i'm using the free heroku account too and installed the heroku scheduler add-on for free. Despite the logs saying 'file not found'. I'm 100% sure the file has been committed and transferred as when i clone the directory back to my pc i receive it..

Comment: You can experiment by using `heroku run php /app/path/to/script.php` and see if that works. Or `heroku run bash` should get you a prompt inside of the heroku terminal so you can move around and test in a more live fashion

Comment: Has anyone tried this and gotten a `permission denied` error when running the file with `heroku run`? Any tips on fixing it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I get bash: php: command not found when I use heroku bash

Comment: The `php` executable is at `bin/php` and is not in the `PATH` in the default PHP buildpack, which is why you're not finding it. See my answer below about a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default PHP buildpack on Heroku does not currently have [PHP CLI support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), so you can only use it to serve web requests via Apache and not for scripts in worker dynos. However, this is possible if you are using a PHP buildpack that does have CLI support.

To test it out, I [forked the PHP buildpack](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-php.git), switched out the PHP binary with one that was compiled with CLI support, and put together small [demo of running a scheduled PHP job on Heroku](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/php-scheduler-demo). See the project's [readme](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/php-scheduler-demo#readme) for step-by-step instructions. To use this fork on an existing app, set the buildpack with:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-php.git
```

Note, the [`release`](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/release#L9-Lundefined) script in my fork sets up the `PATH` to resolve the `php` executable in `/app/bin/php` with just `php`, unlike the default buildpack that woud require using the absolute path.

Comment: I realized I was wrong about the default PHP buildpack not having CLI support, but it does require some tweaks to make it work. See @friism's answer to a related question here for how to tweak it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14390508/129492

Answer (score 5):

**How to run a PHP script with *Heroku Scheduler*?**

#### Testing and setting up the job

With a directory structure and `Procfile` looking something like this:

```
├─ Procfile
├─ web/
├── (your webfiles)
├─ worker/
└── myscript.php
```

`Procfile`:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
worker: php worker/myscript.php
```

Then you can test your worker from the command-line like so:

```
heroku run worker
```

To schedule a job, go into *Heroku Scheduler* and add the job in a similar fashion, but without the `heroku run` segment (else you'll get `bash: heroku: command not found` errors), just:

```
worker
```

Or, alternatively, directly:

```
php worker/myscript.php
```

#### Checking on the job

You can see the job in the app's logs. e.g.:

```
2017-09-01T14:19:37.397210+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9540]: Starting process with command `php worker/myscript.php`
```

#### Notes

- The `worker` name in the `Procfile` could be set to something else. e.g.: `myworker`, `mysuperduperscript`, etc.
- I included a `web` section, but it's optional if all you want is a worker / background service and don't need to serve files on the web.

---

Alternative: if, for whatever reason, you'd rather perform a GET/POST request on a URL, you can use the *Temporize Scheduler* add-on.

Comment: Great answer Fabien!
What if I want to run several cron scripts (worker files) all at once every 10 mins? (and one or two take 20mins to run)